# Modifying a std::vector function (inheritance?)

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, operator-overloading, overloading

I'm porting some Fortran90 code to C++ (because I'm stupid, to save the "Why?!").

Fortran allows specification of ranges on arrays, in particular, starting at negative values, eg

```
double precision :: NameOfArray(FirstSize, -3:3)
```

I can write this in C++ as something like

```
std::array<std::array<double, 7>, FirstSize> NameOfArray;
```

but now I have to index like `NameOfArray[0:FirstSize-1][0:6]`. If I want to index using the Fortran style index, I can write perhaps

```
template <typename T, size_t N, int start>
class customArray
{
public:
    T& operator[](const int idx) { return data_[idx+start]; }
private:
    std::array<T,N> data_;
}
```

and then

```
customArray<double, 7, -3> NameOfArray;
NameOfArray[-3] = 5.2;
NameOfArray[3] = 2.5;
NameOfArray[4] = 3.14; // This is out of bounds, 
                       // despite being a std::array of 7 elements
```

So - the general idea is "Don't inherit from std::'container class here'".
My understanding is that this is because, for example, std::vector does not have a virtual destructor, and so should not (can not?) be used polymorphically.

Is there some other way I can use a `std::array`, `std::vector`, etc, and get their functions 'for free', whilst overriding specific functions?

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
T& std::array<T,N>::operator[](const int idx) { ... };
```

might allow me to override the operator, but it won't give me access to knowledge about a custom start point - making it completely pointless. Additionally, if I were to optimistically think all my `customArray` objects would have the same offset, I could hardcode that value - but then my std::array is broken (I think).

How can I get around this? (Ignoring the simple answer - don't - just write `myArray[idx-3]` as needed)

Comment: As long as you don't add anything that is supposed to be cleaned up by the destructor (e.g. non POD-variables), inherting from a std vector should be OK (alrhough, there might be better solutions to your problem)

Comment: If you are translating from Fortran, you are hardly using the vectors polymorphically, are you? Then the non-virtual destructor argument falls.

Comment: Sorry - reading again I realise it reads as though I was stating that as a reason to not do it here - I rather meant that I understand it's generally to be avoided. I see both of your points - perhaps this is the simplest solution. Regarding 'better solutions' - any suggestions? (Although now I suppose that this is perhaps off-topic at SO)

Comment: I've done this many times, and have always been happy afterward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no problem with inheriting standard containers. This is only **generally discouraged** because this imposes several limitations and such an inheritance is not the way how inheritance was originally predicted in C++ to be used. If you are careful and aware of these limitations, you can safely use inheritance here.

You just need to remember that this **is not subclassing** and what this really means. In particular, you shouldn't use pointers or references to the object of this class. The problem might be if you pass a value of `MyVector<x>*` where `vector<x>*` was expected. You should also never create such objects as dynamic (using `new`), and therefore also `delete` these objects through the pointer to the base class - simply because destructor call will not forward to your class's destructor, as it's not *virtual*.

There's no possibility to prevent casting of the "derived pointer" to the "base pointer", but you can prevent taking a pointer from an object by overloading the `&` operator. You can also prevent creating objects of this class dynamically by declaring an in-class `operator new` in private section (or `= delete` should work as well).

Don't also think about private inheritance. This is merely like containing this thing as a field in private section, except the accessor name.

Comment: A helpful answer detailing some of the problems in simple terms, with concrete examples of what not to do. Thanks also for the comment on private inheritance - this is sometimes seen in similar questions, and then the following `using std::vector::push_back(...)` etc declarations seem to overtake everything.

Comment: Why should this not be subclassing? Especially passing raw pointers is no problem at all. The only situation, in which a problem might occure is, if you are deleting via a base pointer, but when you are using smartpointers even that argument falls.

Comment: Subclassing means that you are using the base class as a framework in which you cover some slots with your implementation. Derivation is generally both things: extending and subclassing. In case when you derive a non-polymorphic class, there's obviously only extending. I've once wrote an article about that:
https://sektorvanskijlen.wordpress.com/2010/12/08/multiple-inheritance-considered-nice/

Comment: I disagree with the third and fourth paragraph. Private base classes `class customArray : private std::vector<float>` **do** prevent the casting to base class pointer outside the class, but inside the class (where you know to be careful) you can write `using` declarations (something you can't do for members)

Comment: Well, my comment about private inheritance was a kind-of mind shortcut. I wrote it exactly because someone might propose private inheritance as a method to prevent casting to a base class. I just explained that even though it has this advantage, there are some disadvantages that makes this feature not fit the user needs. In particular, he'd still have to provide declarations that would expose all methods of the derived class, even though instead of real method definitions, they'd be just `using` statements.

Comment: @MSalters, I used exactly that approach (`private` inheritance and `using`) in my answer. (Not sure if you had commented first!) `private` inheritance is perfect for this problem precisely because we don't really want the *is-a* relationship in this case. We want to build a new, distinct, type `customArray` by "copying-and-pasting" the code from `array` and modifying some things. I guess we agree on this?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: Indeed. Reuse what you can, replace what you must. Hide what's irrelevant, but that is automatic.

Comment: You are both right guys, of course, and it's really a matter of balance. With private inheritance you are just free to expose only selected part of the public interface of that private class. With public inheritance you just expose everything. Limiting the public interface of the underlying vector isn't always good because you limit also any future extensions. Although OTOH it should be done if you are unsure if in future the "base class" will be added new methods that deal with the index, and that's exactly what this class would like to avoid.

Answer (score 4):

A range converter class could be the solution although you would need to make it yourself, but it would allow you to get the range size to initialize the vector and to do the conversion.

Untested code:

```
struct RangeConv // [start,end[
{
  int start, end;
  RangeConv(int s, int e) : start(s), end(e) { }
  int size() const { return end - start; }
  int operator()(int i) { return i - start; } // possibly check whether in range
}

RangeConv r(-3, 3);
std::vector<int> v(r.size());
v[r(-3)] = 5;
```

Comment: An interesting idea, but this is practically the same as `v[idx - offset]`. Nonetheless, slightly nicer looking and avoids any problems with memory allocation, pointer types, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> so should not (can not?) be used polymorphically.

Don't give up too soon. There are basically two issues to consider with inheritance in C++.

### Lifetime

Such objects, derived classes with non-virtual destructors in the base, can be used safely in a polymorphic fashion, if you basically follow one simple rule: don't use `delete` anywhere. This naturally means that you cannot use `new`. You generally should be avoiding `new` and raw pointers in modern C++ anyway. `shared_ptr` will do the right thing, i.e. safely call the correct destructor, as long as you use `make_shared`:

```
std:: shared_ptr<Base> bp = std:: make_shared<Derived>( /* constructor args */ );
```

The type parameter to `make_shared`, in this case `Derived`, not only controls which type is created. It also controls which destructor is called. (Because the underlying shared-pointer object will store an appropriate deleter.)

It's tempting to use `unique_ptr`, but unfortunately (by default) it will lead to the wrong deleter being used (i.e. it will naively use `delete` directly on the base pointer). It's unfortunate that, alongside the default `unique_ptr`, there isn't a much-safer-but-less-efficient `unique_ptr_with_nice_deleter` built into the standard.

### Polymorphism

Even if `std::array` did have a virtual destructor, this current design would still be very weird. Because `operator[]` is not virtual, then casting from `customArray*` to `std:: array*` would lead to the wrong `operator[]`. This isn't really a C++-specific issue, it's basically the issue that you shouldn't pretend that `customArray` *isa* `std:: array`.

Instead, just decide that `customArray` is a separate type. This means you couldn't pass an `customArray*` to a function expecting `std::array*` - but are you sure you even want that anyway?

> Is there some other way I can use a std::array, std::vector, etc, and get their functions 'for free', whilst overloading specific functions?

This is a good question. You do *not* want your new type to satisfy *isa* `std::array`. You just want it to behave very similar to it. As if you magically copied-and-pasted all the code from `std::array` to create a new type. And then you want to adjust some things.

Use `private` inheritance, and `using` clauses to bring in the code you want:

```
template <typename T, size_t N, int start>
struct customArray : private std::array<T,N>
{
    // first, some functions to 'copy-and-paste' as-is
    using std::array<T,N>  :: front;
    using std::array<T,N>  :: begin;

    // finally, the functions you wish to modify
    T& operator[](const int idx) { return data_[idx+start]; }
}
```

The `private` inheritance will block conversions from `customArray *` to `std::array *`, and that's what we want.

*PS:* I have very little experience with `private` inheritance like this. So many it's not the best solution - any feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**General thought**

The recommendation not to inherit from standard vector, is because this kind of construct is often misunderstood, and some people are tempted to make all kind of objects inherit from a vector, just for minor convenience.

But this rule should'nt become a dogma. Especially if your goal is to make a vector class, and if you know what you're doing.

**Danger 1: inconsistency**

If you have a very important codebase working with vectors in the range 1..size instead of 0..size-1, you could opt for keeping it according to this logic, in order not to add thousands of -1 to indexes, +1 to index displayed, and +1 for sizes.

A valid approach could be to use something like:

```
template <class T> 
class vectorone : public vector<T> {
    public: 
    T& operator[] (typename vector<T>::size_type n) { return vector<T>::operator[] (n-1); }
const T& operator[] (typename vector<T>::size_type n) const { return  vector<T>::operator[] (n-1); }
};
```

But you have to remain consitent accross all the vector interface :

- First, there's also a `const T& operator[]()`.  If youd don't overload it, you'll end up having wrong behaviour if you have vectors in constant objects.
- Then, and it's missing above, theres's also an `at()` which shall be consitent with `[]`
- Then you have to take extreme care with the constructors, as there are many of them, to be sure that your arguments will not be misinterpreted.

So you have free functionality, but there's more work ahead than initially thougt.  The option of creating your own object with a more limited interface, and a private vector could in the end be a safer approach.

**Danger 2:more inconsistency**

The vector indexes are  `vector<T>::size_type`.  Unfortunately this type is unsigned.  The impact of inherit from vector, but redefine `operator[]` with signed integer indexes has to be carefully analysed. This can lead to subtle bugs according to the way the indexes are defined.

**Conclusions:**

There's perhap's more work that you think to offer a consistent `std::vector` interface.  So in the end, having your own class using a private vector could be the safer approach.

You should also consider that your code will be maintained one day by people without fortran background, and they might have wrong assumptions about the `[]` in your code.  Is going native c++ really out of question ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem that bad to just stick with composition, and write wrappers for the member functions you need. There aren't that many. I'd even be tempted to make the `array` data member public so you can access it directly when needed, although some people would consider that a bigger no-no than inheriting from a base class without a virtual destructor.

```
template <typename T, size_t N, int start>
class customArray
{
public:
    std::array<T,N> data;

    T& operator[](int idx) { return data[idx+start]; }
    auto begin() { return data.begin(); }
    auto begin() const { return data.begin(); }
    auto end() { return data.end(); }
    auto end() const { return data.end(); }
    auto size() const { return data.size(); }
};

int main() {
    customArray<int, 7, -3> a;
    a.data.fill(5);  // can go through the `data` member...
    for (int& i : a) // ...or the wrapper functions (begin/end).
        cout << i << endl;
}
```